# What's the best way to store a decision table in a config file?

Tags: c#, configuration, configuration-files, config

I'm looking to store a decision table similar to this example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_table#example in some sort of config file but can't think of a format that would be clean.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why use a configuration file? Why not code?  In some languages, code can be imported at run time.  What's wrong with that?

Comment: Do you need to config it manually/ without running the application?

Comment: @S.Lott The reason I'd like to put it in a config file is so that I can edit it without requiring a code change and recompile. I should mention that I'm working in C#.

Comment: @Winfred I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. It is not a requirement that the decision table be stored in a config file, but it seems like that's a better choice than hardcoding the decision table in code.

Comment: @Matthew would a serialized object an option for you? But you would need another program to open and edit the decision table. Otherwise, just use XML as it is flexible enough, although parsing is a bit slower than other common config file structures.

Comment: @Matthew: (1) Don't "mention" that you're working in C#.  **Update** the question.  Change the tags.  (2) A decision table is code.  Changing it is a code change.  Trying to fudge a code change seems to be an accident waiting to happen.  (3) What's wrong with BRML?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_Rules_Markup_Language

Comment: What's wrong with BRML? 1) abandoned. 2) XML. 3) IBM.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a config file, you should write your own config section.

[How to: Create Custom Configuration Sections Using ConfigurationSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could also make an Excel Spreadsheet and save the sheet as XML. Parsing the Excel XML format is reasonable okay to do, but it really depends on your needs how far you want to go.